# Xamarin forms android throw null exception after updating Xamarin forms to 5.0.0.2401

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have updated Xamarin Forms to latest version(5.0.0.2401).
It is working fine in iOS. In android first it returns **Error: Could not find 2 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages: - Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter, Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette**. After that I have added these 2 packages.
Now It will debug without error but it does not deploy in android. It returns **System.NullReferenceException** has been thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object error and in stack trace it returns the following error.

*at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x0001d] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:111
at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(intptr,intptr,intptr).*

Target Android version - v10.0

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: For the error message, install the `Android X assemblies` would be fixed. For the NullReferenceException, could you provide more deails about which line of the code causes this error?

Comment: Issue has been fixed by updating Visual studio and removing layout folder.

Comment: Facing the same issues, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, in my case Android Camera 2 API  => "cameraPage.OpenCamera()" causes the crash. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Facing the same issue. But on Xamarin Forms Version 5.0.0.2337.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue with Camera2, and i can see the following in the output debug console when shifting between pages that have the control and then trying to navigate to another page.

I find that if i'm slow in my user actions, the app seems stable. Although, if i rush and navigate quickly, the app does crash with the following.

After changing pages this appears in the Debug Console.

```
[MessageQueue] Handler (android.os.Handler) {e7ad8fd} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
[MessageQueue] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {e7ad8fd} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
[MessageQueue]  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:560)
[MessageQueue]  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:778)
[MessageQueue]  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:727)
[MessageQueue]  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:697)
[MessageQueue]  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:427)
[MessageQueue]  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraHandlerExecutor.execute(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2302)
[MessageQueue]  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy.onClosed(CallbackProxies.java:104)
[MessageQueue]  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:588)
[MessageQueue]  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.finalize(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:879)
[MessageQueue]  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
[MessageQueue]  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
[MessageQueue]  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
[MessageQueue]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

This appears after crashing and attempting to load between Shell Pages quickly..

```
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=1323ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=1360448, IntendedVsync=100388678577668, Vsync=100389828577622, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=100389841897744, AnimationStart=100389841906130, PerformTraversalsStart=100389842887067, DrawStart=100389992949619, FrameDeadline=100388695244334, FrameInterval=100389841589150, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=100389996757588, SyncStart=100389997235609, IssueDrawCommandsStart=100389997569046, SwapBuffers=100389999503421, FrameCompleted=100390002199567, DequeueBufferDuration=29323, QueueBufferDuration=1906198, GpuCompleted=100390001411286, SwapBuffersCompleted=100390002199567, DisplayPresentTime=64544768526125, 
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #2
The thread 0x2 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #38
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12 
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V (_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz) [0x0001c] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:23 
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(intptr,intptr)
[BpBinder] onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>
[BpBinder] onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>
```

Using Visual Studio 17.2.3
Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2401

This was stable a few weeks ago, and something i tried to change was the AppShell Layout, from using

```
<TabBar>
<Tab>
        <ShellContent ... />
        <ShellContent ... />
        <ShellContent ... />
</Tab>
</TabBar>
```

to

```
<TabBar>
<ShellContent ... />
<ShellContent ... />
<ShellContent ... />
</TabBar>
```

It's strange, but the app i can navigate quickly between pages now and it seems almost stable, while testing now, it's more rare that it crashes with the same error, than before.
Is this a rendering issue of some sort ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2022 preview then update the following setting:

1. Right-click on the Android project and select properties.
2. Select Android options.
3. Check the `Use Fast Deployment` (debug mode only)

**Screenshot:**
[image]